# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'FilterSetMetaclass' and 'ID'

Tags: graphene-python, graphene-django

I am having some issues with my django app since updating my dependencies.  I updated django from 2.2.28 to 3.2. The python version in the application is 3.6. I have problem with graphen.

Error:

```
  File ".../backend_django_3/kidsview-backend/preschool/schema.py", line 1689, in Query
    daily_activity = graphene.Node.Field(DailyActivityNode, filterset_class=DailyActivityFilter)
  File ".../.virtualenvs/kidsview_django_3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphene/relay/node.py", line 86, in Field
    return NodeField(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../.virtualenvs/kidsview_django_3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphene/relay/node.py", line 56, in __init__
    super(NodeField, self).__init__(
  File ".../.virtualenvs/kidsview_django_3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphene/types/field.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.args = to_arguments(args or OrderedDict(), extra_args)
  File ".../.virtualenvs/kidsview_django_3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphene/types/argument.py", line 80, in to_arguments
    extra_args = sorted(extra_args.items(), key=lambda f: f[1])
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'FilterSetMetaclass' and 'ID'
[27/Jun/2022 13:23:22] "POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 500 253983
```

This is a large application I chose specific libraries:

```
aniso8601==7.0.0
asgiref==3.5.2
Django==3.2
django-anymail==6.1.0
django-colorfield==0.1.15
django-cors-headers==3.13.0
django-debug-toolbar==3.2.2
django-extensions==2.2.3
django-filter==21.1
django-graphiql-debug-toolbar==0.1.3
django-graphql-extensions==0.1.0
django-graphql-jwt==0.3.4
django-health-check==3.14.3
django-model-utils==4.2.0
django-nested-inline==0.4.4
django-qr-code==2.2.0
django-safedelete==1.0.0
django-silk==4.0.1
django-simple-history==2.8.0
django-solo==1.1.3
django-stdimage==2.4.1
django-storages==1.12.2
django-tinymce==2.8.0
graphene==2.1.9
graphene-django==2.15.0
graphene-file-upload==1.3.0
graphql-core==2.3.2
graphql-relay==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.1
jsonschema==3.2.0
openpyxl==3.0.5
packaging==21.0
parso==0.8.2
phonenumbers==8.10.20
Pillow==8.3.1
progressbar2==3.53.1
prometheus-client==0.8.0
promise==2.3
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
ptyprocess==0.7.0
Pygments==2.10.0
PyJWT==2.4.0
PyNaCl==1.4.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
PyPDF2==1.26.0
pyrsistent==0.18.0
python-bidi==0.4.2
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-docx==0.8.11
python-jose-cryptodome==1.3.2
python-utils==2.5.6
pytz==2021.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
qrcode==6.1
singledispatch==3.7.0
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
```

Anyone have any idea what the problem is?